# Compare password in MEAN

Tags: node.js, bcrypt

Here is the code. My password is not encrypted and I want to compare it normally, not as `bcrypt.compare`. How should I modify the above one?

```js
userSchema.methods.comparePassword = function (candidatePassword, callback) 
{
  bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, this.password, function (err, isMatch) {
    if (err) {
        return callback(err);
    }
    callback(null, isMatch);
  });
};
```

Comment: This is an uncommonly bad idea, to not hash a password.

Comment: My friend  needs to access the password from mobile api so i am in situation to do that

Comment: That changes nothing. You can allow mobile apps to have access w/o storing your passwords in the clear.

Answer (score 1):

```
userSchema.methods.comparePassword = function (candidatePassword) {
    if(this.password == candidatePassword) return true
    else return false

};
//   user is instance of mongoose find 
if(user.comparePassword(password))
    console.log("password matched")
```

Answer (score 1):

Direct comparison of password is not a good idea as there is a vulnerability as given this [article](https://snyk.io/blog/node-js-timing-attack-ccc-ctf/)

It is always a good idea to use bcrypt.compare.